# How to get help on Doom's own functions

Tags: help, doom, documentation

I use `describe-function` command with `SPC h f` to get help on emacs functions. But I want to get documentation on Doom's own functions such as `map!`. `describe-function` doesn't list this function. How can I get documentation on this and other custom functions?

Comment: That's a macro, but you should be able to get help on macros with describe-function https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/1274de3d34cb4ad60375154ff38236b7985d95ec/core/core-keybinds.el#L409 Maybe the macro isn't loaded?  Not very familiar with loading, and not at all with doom, but I think often interactive functions and macros are autoloaded and that this one isn't, maybe because it's not interactive?  Surprises me if it's not loaded though, given the filename

Comment: If you evaluate this lisp in `*scratch*`, what does it say? `(fboundp 'map!)`

Comment: @CroadLangshan It returns `t`

Comment: Odd.  In spacemacs, if I copy-paste that macro and evaluate it I can run `describe-function` on it and it shows up in the list (I think I'm actually getting `counsel-describe-function` that way, though -- maybe plain describe-function doesn't show macro help??  seems unlikely)

Comment: Just tried in vanilla emacs, `describe-function` works fine there too.

Comment: @CroadLangshan `describe-function` works for example for `map` and other functions but not for `map!`. Thank you anyway, I can check the documentation using the github source files.

Comment: This seems to be something to do with ivy / counsel.  If I disable ivy-mode and copy the definition of describe-function to describe-function-2 and evaluate that (to avoid counsel messing with it via advice or whatever), then run that, it works.  Also in spacemacs (but not doom), if I put point somewhere in a buffer that says `map!`, describe-function lists it -- but otherwise, it doesn't show up.  In doom it never shows up unless I go to the lenghs above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ivy, this is expected. [Ivy's user manual](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#ivy--regex-plus) states that Ivy uses the exclamation mark for regex negation:

> Ivy supports regexp negation with "!". For example, "define key ! ivy quit" first selects everything matching "define.*key", then removes everything matching "ivy", and finally removes everything matching "quit". What remains is the final result set of the negation regexp.

> Since Ivy treats minibuffer input as a regexp, the standard regexp identifiers work: "^", "$", "\b" or "[a-z]". The exceptions are spaces, which translate to ".*", and "!" that signal the beginning of a negation group.

You should get what you need if you escape the exclamation mark. In other words, when you use `describe-function`, search for

```
map\!
```

Comment: Can you please explain why? Is `!` a special character that needs escaping? Or is this something else? Is that special to Doom? Is it something to do with `ivy/counsel` as a comment mentions or is that unrelated? Is it a Doom bug?

Comment: I'm not sure I can, I'm relatively new to Emacs myself, but using the backslash does help finding "Doom's own functions" so I thought it answered the question. If you feel like this answer should be deleted or relegated to a comment I can do so.

Comment: No, not at all: I'm just trying to make sure that it is as helpful as possible. It would help if the OP chimed in on whether it solved his problem.

Comment: Hi @NickD I went ahead and added some information to my answer, hopefully it's more helpful now. Thank you for the input!